# Check if on root domain and execute, else don't?

Tags: php

I was looking to create a php function that checks if the current page is in the root folder and if it is, it then executes or returns something, else it does nothing. How could this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/' || strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === 0) {
    // something
} else {
    // something else
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `/product.php` also qualify?

Comment: `__FILE__` contains the system path of the currently running file, e.g., `/var/www/html/public_html/somefile.php`. It will never be contained within `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 1):

You mean root URI (basically URL for web script) stored inside [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), or you mean [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`) to be inside root dir?

Anyway, you can use one of these two and then strip filename using [`dirname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php), or [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for URI:

```
dirname(__FILE__) == '/';
dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

Comment: What if he places the function inside an include file? Wouldn't it always return the containing directory of *that* file, rather than the directory of the file that included it?

Comment: Than he could use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, not that proficient with programming. What I mean is, if the functions runs on example.com it returns something, but if it runs on example.com/anythingelse it returns something else.

Comment: Also, how could I edit it so it returns the same thing at example.com and example.com/something/ but returns something else for example.com/anythingelse ?